PowerApps Question - Automatically re-populate submitted form with data
I have a multi-screen PowerApps SP form, where the user can enter data on the first page, save/submit data on the first page, then with the app still open, continue to other screens.  My question is, how can I re-populate that first form with data I just entered?  If a user fills out the fields on the fist page, clicks submit (they're automatically navigated the the next screen after submitting), then navigates back to that first screen, I want those fields to be populated with the entered data.  The formmode on that first screen is just FormMode.New, so I'd think I need to modify that...though I'm not sure.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Yes, you will need to change the form mode to "Edit" and set "Item" property of form control to that respective list item. Try it and let me know if it works for you.

The quick and easy answer is to add EditForm(SharePointForm1) (or whatever your form name is) to whatever control is navigating back to the first screen.
However, I can only assume there's other considerations to factor in. If that's the case, I think we'd need a fair bit more information about your PowerApp to provide a better answer.
